# Issue symfony 5.1 EntityType form

Tags: php, forms, symfony, entity

I currently have a problem on a project under symfony 5.1, I want to create a registration form in which the user must select a city (I store the list of cities in a separate table). To do this I use EntityType to display a select with all my cities. However it returns the following error:

The target-entity App\Entity\typeUser cannot be found in 'App\Entity\User#typeUser'.

Here is my registration form

```html
<?php

namespace App\Form;

use App\Entity\User;
use App\Entity\Ville;
use App\Entity\Formations;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CheckboxType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\PasswordType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\IsTrue;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Length;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\NotBlank;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\EmailType;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;


class RegistrationFormType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $builder
            ->add('email', EmailType::class, [
                'label'=> "Email : ",
            ])
            ->add('agreeTerms', CheckboxType::class, [
                'mapped' => False,
                'label'=> "Acceptez vous nos termes ? ",
                'constraints' => [
                    new IsTrue([
                        'message' => 'You should agree to our terms.',
                    ]),
                ],
            ])
            ->add('plainPassword', PasswordType::class, [
                // instead of being set onto the object directly,
                // this is read and encoded in the controller
                'label'=>"Mot de passe :   ",
                'mapped' => false,
                'attr' => ['autocomplete' => 'new-password'],
                'constraints' => [
                    new NotBlank([
                        'message' => 'Please enter a password',
                    ]),
                    new Length([
                        'min' => 6,
                        'minMessage' => 'Your password should be at least {{ limit }} characters',
                        // max length allowed by Symfony for security reasons
                        'max' => 4096,
                    ]),
                ],
            ])
            ->add('nom', TextType::class, [
                'label' => "Nom : ",
            ])
            ->add('prenom', TextType::class, [
                'label' => "Prénom : ",
            ])
            ->add('permis', CheckboxType::class, [
                'label' => "Avez-vous le miper ? ",
            ])
            ->add('telephone', TextType::class, [
                'label' => "téléphone : " ,
            ])
            ->add('dateNaissance', TextType::class, [
                'label' => "Date de naissance : ",
            ])
            ->add('adresse', TextType::class, [
                'label' => "Adresse : ",
            ])
            ->add('ville', EntityType::class, [
                'label' => "ville : ",
                'class' => Ville::class,
                'choice_label' => 'ville',
            ]);
       
     }  
        


    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => User::class,
            
        ]);
    }
}
```

My Cities entity

```html
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\VilleRepository;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use App\Entity\User;


/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=VilleRepository::class)
 */
class Ville
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $ville;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", nullable=true)
     */
    private $codePostal;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", nullable=true)
     */
    private $latitude;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", nullable=true)
     */
    private $longitude;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=User::class, mappedBy="ville")
     */
    private $users;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->users = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getVille(): ?string
    {
        return $this->ville;
    }

    public function setVille(?string $ville): self
    {
        $this->ville = $ville;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getCodePostal(): ?int
    {
        return $this->codePostal;
    }

    public function setCodePostal(?int $codePostal): self
    {
        $this->codePostal = $codePostal;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getLatitude(): ?int
    {
        return $this->latitude;
    }

    public function setLatitude(?int $latitude): self
    {
        $this->latitude = $latitude;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getLongitude(): ?int
    {
        return $this->longitude;
    }

    public function setLongitude(?int $longitude): self
    {
        $this->longitude = $longitude;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection<int, User>
     */
    public function getUsers(): Collection
    {
        return $this->users;
    }

    public function addUser(User $user): self
    {
        if (!$this->users->contains($user)) {
            $this->users[] = $user;
            $user->setVille($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeUser(User $user): self
    {
        if ($this->users->removeElement($user)) {
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($user->getVille() === $this) {
                $user->setVille(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

My User entity

```html
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\UserRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use App\Entity\Ville;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=UserRepository::class)
 * @ORM\Table(name="`user`")
 * @UniqueEntity(fields={"email"}, message="There is already an account with this email")
 */
class User implements UserInterface
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=180, unique=true)
     */
    private $email;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="json")
     */
    private $roles = [];

    /**
     * @var string The hashed password
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    private $password;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $nom;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $prenom;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean", nullable=true)
     */
    private $permis;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $telephone;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="date", nullable=true)
     */
    private $dateNaissance;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $adresse;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean", nullable=true)
     */
    private $handicap;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", nullable=true)
     */
    private $moyenneAvis;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean", nullable=true)
     */
    private $premiereConnexion;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=typeUser::class, inversedBy="users")
     */
    private $typeUser;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=Formations::class, inversedBy="users")
     */
    private $formation;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Ville::class", inversedBy="users")
     */
    private $ville;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getEmail(): ?string
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    public function setEmail(string $email): self
    {
        $this->email = $email;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * A visual identifier that represents this user.
     *
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function getUsername(): string
    {
        return (string) $this->email;
    }

    /**
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function getRoles(): array
    {
        $roles = $this->roles;
        // guarantee every user at least has ROLE_USER
        $roles[] = 'ROLE_USER';

        return array_unique($roles);
    }

    public function setRoles(array $roles): self
    {
        $this->roles = $roles;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function getPassword(): string
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

    public function setPassword(string $password): self
    {
        $this->password = $password;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Returning a salt is only needed, if you are not using a modern
     * hashing algorithm (e.g. bcrypt or sodium) in your security.yaml.
     *
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function getSalt(): ?string
    {
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function eraseCredentials()
    {
        // If you store any temporary, sensitive data on the user, clear it here
        // $this->plainPassword = null;
    }

    public function getNom(): ?string
    {
        return $this->nom;
    }

    public function setNom(?string $nom): self
    {
        $this->nom = $nom;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getPrenom(): ?string
    {
        return $this->prenom;
    }

    public function setPrenom(?string $prenom): self
    {
        $this->prenom = $prenom;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getPermis(): ?bool
    {
        return $this->permis;
    }

    public function setPermis(?bool $permis): self
    {
        $this->permis = $permis;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getTelephone(): ?string
    {
        return $this->telephone;
    }

    public function setTelephone(?string $telephone): self
    {
        $this->telephone = $telephone;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getDateNaissance(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->dateNaissance;
    }

    public function setDateNaissance(?\DateTimeInterface $dateNaissance): self
    {
        $this->dateNaissance = $dateNaissance;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getAdresse(): ?string
    {
        return $this->adresse;
    }

    public function setAdresse(?string $adresse): self
    {
        $this->adresse = $adresse;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getHandicap(): ?bool
    {
        return $this->handicap;
    }

    public function setHandicap(?bool $handicap): self
    {
        $this->handicap = $handicap;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getMoyenneAvis(): ?int
    {
        return $this->moyenneAvis;
    }

    public function setMoyenneAvis(?int $moyenneAvis): self
    {
        $this->moyenneAvis = $moyenneAvis;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getPremiereConnexion(): ?bool
    {
        return $this->premiereConnexion;
    }

    public function setPremiereConnexion(?bool $premiereConnexion): self
    {
        $this->premiereConnexion = $premiereConnexion;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getTypeUser(): ?typeUser
    {
        return $this->typeUser;
    }

    public function setTypeUser(?typeUser $typeUser): self
    {
        $this->typeUser = $typeUser;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getFormation(): ?Formations
    {
        return $this->formation;
    }

    public function setFormation(?Formations $formation): self
    {
        $this->formation = $formation;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getVille(): ?Ville
    {
        return $this->ville;
    }

    public function setVille(?Ville $ville): self
    {
        $this->ville = $ville;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

I hope that I have been clear enough for you to help me.

Thank you in advance for your answers :)

Comment: `ManyToOne(targetEntity=typeUser::class,`

Comment: Thank you very much,it works,  I was too confident about my entities because of self creation.